# Non-linear scale of ammeter?

Tags: current, inductor, measurement

Recently some one asked me 'Why ammeter (based on moving coil principle) has a non-linear scale?' In multimeters (not based on moving coil principle) which we uses in digital lab, I didn't found any non-linearity in scale?

Can someone provide any reason why this is happening?

Comment: moving coil meters are linear,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think whoever made that claim was somewhat confused. [Galvanometer](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/magnetic/galvan.html#c1)-based ammeters are [pretty linear](https://books.google.com/books?id=qPi-SSchB6MC&pg=PA105). He was probably thinking of ["moving iron meter"](https://books.google.com/books?id=qPi-SSchB6MC&pg=PA106), which is indeed non-linear; the deflection in those is proportional with the square of the current, so the screen might look like:

[image]

The difference in linearity between galvanometer and moving-iron meter these is owed to the fact in the former the flux density is constant, while in the latter, the movement of the iron increases the flux, so it's a form of positive feedback if you like.

It's actually possible to manipulate the geometry of the coil so that the moving-iron meter is somewhat linear in parts of its scale, as shown on this Wikipedia example:

[image]

Comment: moving iron meterc can be linear on non-linear depending on the shape of the iron.

Comment: @Jasen: yes, they can be made that way... to some extent (added an example of that).

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @Respawned Fluff's answer, there's yet  another type of analog device which doesn't use a moving coil. But as I'm not sure if you use the term "moving coil" to just distinguish between analog an digital devices, I'll write about it.

I don't know the English name for this type and found this German sketch on [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitzdrahtmesswerk):

[image]
*Honina at the German language Wikipedia [GFDL (http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) or CC-BY-SA-3.0 (http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/)], via Wikimedia Commons*

Though labeled in German, the principle should  be clear: The red wire expands due to the heat generated by the current through it. This expansion is mapped to the pointer.

The expansion of the wire is linear to its temperature, which is (in first order) linear to the power and so to the square of the current through the wire. The displacement of the brown string also is linear to the expansion in first order. 
**Finally, the scale is linear to the square of the current, as also shown in the sketch.**

The benefit of this type of amperemeter is that it works with DC, but also AC (RMS) over a large frequency range. As the pointer is not sensitive to vibrations (i.e. would not swing that much when you shake the device), this type was (is?) used in cars as temperature / fuel / pressure / speed(?) gauge.

Comment: It's a "hot wire ammeter".

Answer (score 0):

Also an ammeter that is used for measuring AC currents will be nonlinear because of the drops of the diode rectifier that is incorporated.